# Error in `python3': free(): invalid pointer

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, error-handling, glob

I'm trying to read all the csv files in 2 directories using glob module:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob


def get_list_of_group_df(filepath):
    all_group_df_list = []

    groups_path = filepath
    for file in glob.glob(groups_path):
        name = os.path.basename(file)
        name = patient_name.partition('_raw')[0]

        with open(file, 'r') as name_vcf:
            group_vcf_to_df = pd.read_csv(name_vcf, delimiter='\t', 
            header=0, index_col=False, low_memory=False,             
            usecols=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) 

            group_df_wo_duplicates = group_vcf_to_df.drop_duplicates()
            group_df = group_df_wo_duplicates.reset_index(drop=True)
            group_df['group_name'] = name
            all_group_df_list.append(group_df)

    return all_group_df_list

def get_freq():

    group_filepath_dict = 
  {'1_group':"/home/Raw_group/*.tsv",

'2_group':"/home/Raw_group/*.tsv"}
    for group, filepath in group_filepath_dict.items():
        print(get_list_of_group_df(filepath))


get_freq()
```

When I run this script locally, it works just fine. However, running it on UBUNTU server gives me the following error message:

```
Error in `python3': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fcc970d76be ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm using python 3.6.3 version. Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Does it say in which line that is?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Hm ... seems more like a general problem to me. Like with the Python installation or with the permissions for executing the script or accessing the files.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem in Python 3.7.3 under Raspbian Buster 2020-02-13. My program dies with `free(): invalid pointer` except no pointer is given and there is no core dump and no stack trace. So, I have nothing to debug with. This has happened a few times, usually after the program has been running for a day or two, so I suspect it's a very slow memory leak or a very infrequent intermittent bug in Python garbage collection. I am not doing any memory management myself.